# how to read the value of a property in a json object in ionic 3

Tags: json, angular, ionic3

I'm working on a project in ionic 3,and am trying to do a login functionality in my app with php and mysql. but i got a problem reading data from json object to illustrate the situation,
I have a table called "user" in my database, and I feched with php all the records and showed them as a json format like this:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include ("cnx.php");
$query="select * from ionic_test ";
$result=$cnx->query($query);

$rs['user']=[];
while($record=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $rs['user'][]=$record;
}
echo json_encode($rs);
```

[image: php code]

I got this result:

```
 {"user":[{"user":"abdel","pwd":"abdel"}]}
```

so,in my ionic project ,i have created a service which will connect to the php page and get the result shown above from it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
  private url:string
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  this.url='http://localhost/ionic%20login/api.php'
  }

  getusers(){
   return this.http.get(this.url)
  }
```

[image: service]

now, whene I try to read the data returned by the httpClint request ,I got problems, I don't know actually  how to get access to that data, I have tried many ways to read it but none of theme works for me,I always get "undefined" as a result :

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private authProvider:AuthProvider) {    
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.authProvider.getusers().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

the data which i want to read from the json object is this:

[image: the data that i want to read from json object]

I hope that was clear enough to illustrate my problem,and i will be thankful if anyone can help me solve this problem .

Any suggestions or ways to do a  login functionality with  ionic 3 php and mysql is also appreciated.

Comment: so what does your method (getusers) return? error? or data?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what exactly the problem is. For example does data appear in your console and you just don;t know how to access it?

Comment: If you are accessing user object use `data.user[0]`

Comment: yes,my method returns "data" but i don't know how to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

Typechecking of response can be done by  using type parameter

```
 export interface Response {
      user: string;
      pwd: string;

    }
```

`Http` returns an `observable` and We can tell the `HttpClient.get` to return `response` as Response type When we use `http.get<Response[]>(...)` then it returns the instance of `Observable<Response[]>` type. 
In your service

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Response} from './responseModel'
        @Injectable()
        export class AuthProvider {
          private url:string
          constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
          this.url='http://localhost/ionic%20login/api.php'
          }

      getusers()Observable<Response[]>{
       return this.http.get<Response[]>(this.url)
      }
```

In your component subscribe to `Observable<Response>` to get instance of Response

```
 public response=[];
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private authProvider:AuthProvider) {    
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.authProvider.getusers().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.response=data;
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: why would you declare response as empty array and then just assign object to it? just wonder if declaring response type like you did allows that

Comment: @user8705359 done!.. i still a novice and i didn't really know how things are going here ... thank you

Comment: @user8705359 glad I could help! I have updated  my answer too